# Creating popup using Return in pandastable

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

How can I customize the package `panastable` so that when i press `Return` in the display, a warning pops up. I tried to bind `Return` to the function `callback`, which should create the `messagebox`. But nothing happens. It should give the warning after I enter new content in the cell and press `Return`. This is code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class MyTable(Table):

    def callback(self, event):
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Achtung", message="Achtung")

    def showWarning(self):
        self.bind('<Return>', self.callback)

top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry("300x1000")

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["column1"] = [1,2,3,4,5]

frame = tk.Frame(top)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

pt = MyTable(frame, dataframe=df)
pt.show()
pt.focus_set()
pt.showWarning()

button = tk.Button(top, text="Änderungen speichern", command=top.quit)
button.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: you never call `showWarning`, how is it supposed to bind the enter key to anything?, I'd suggest that you use the bind in the `__init__` method or at least call `pt.showWarning()` at some point after declaring `pt`

Comment: How do I add it to the `__init__` method?

Comment: as you do with any other method just define it inside the class (also based on that you seem to need to look at some OOP tutorials), but again that is not necessary, you really currently only need to put `pt.showWarning()` somewhere before calling `.mainloop` and it should work

Comment: unfortunately adding `pt.showWarning()` does not help. Still nothing happens when I use `Return`

Comment: is the keyboard focus set on the widget?

Comment: I tried adding `frame.focus_set()`, but still nothing

Comment: you probably need to do `pt.focus_set()` as that is what you are binding to

Comment: I tried that as well, but nothing

Comment: can you please [edit] the question to include your current code (with these attempts)?

Comment: btw you should notify when you have edited question to include additional info, otherwise we won't know unless we look at your question manually. Now, I can't reproduce the problem, when I run the code and immediately press return key it raises an error (which should be dealt by `from tkinter import messagebox` and then in the function use `messagebox.showinfo(...)` (without `self`)) but other than that the binding works and I can't reproduce a problem where pressing return key (while focus is on the table) does nothing

Comment: Thanks for the tip. True, it works when I am on the spreadsheet. However, the warning should come when  return is pressed in a cell. I guess the focus must then be changed to the respective cell.

Comment: I updated my question regarding `Tkinter messagebox` .

Comment: A `Entry` widget will be created dynamically when you tried to edit a cell and the focus will be in the entry.  So the binding on the table does not work at that time.  Try binding on the window instead.

Comment: @acw1668 btw I discovered in the source code that the entry already has a function bound to it with sequence `<Return>` which can be overridden (so add what is supposed to happen on return (in this case a dialog has to appear) to the inherited method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a much better approach to this IMO (because using what is inherited):

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class MyTable(Table):
    
    @staticmethod
    def show_info():
        messagebox.showwarning(title="Achtung", message="Achtung")

    def handleCellEntry(self, row, col):
        super().handleCellEntry(row, col)
        self.show_info()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x1000")

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["column1"] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

pt = MyTable(frame, dataframe=df)
pt.show()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Änderungen speichern", command=root.quit)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Using the inherited method `handleCellEntry` which is called when enter key is pressed while editing the entry, just what you seem to need. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/blob/4d5bb5ac0e57f0880873eb2b65a178406e1947c7/pandastable/core.py#L3241) how this method is bound to `'<Return>'` sequence to that specific entry (so just override it, call the super method (so it does what it is supposed to do) and then your own method (or vice versa but then the entry will be changed only after you close the dialog)).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was binding it the `top window`. The following code get the wanted result:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry("300x1000")

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["column1"] = [1,2,3,4,5]

frame = tk.Frame(top)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

def callback(*args):
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Achtung", message="Achtung")

top.bind('<Return>', callback)

pt = Table(frame, dataframe=df)
pt.show()


button = tk.Button(top, text="Änderungen speichern", command=top.quit)
button.pack()

top.mainloop()
```